# Github page template not working

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I've my github page, for some reason isn't processing the template, look at http://dleo.github.io/.

Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon checking your github repository https://github.com/dleo/dleo.github.io I have noticed that you have `.nojekyll` file which indicates you are using plain HTML site not a Jekyll site.

In order to make the templates work it should be a Jekyll site, please remove the `.nojekyll` file the the template will work.